# Rename columns in dataframe after transposing dataframe

Tags: r

```
x1=c(55,60,75,80)
x2=c(30,20,15,23)
x3=c(4,3,2,6)
x=data.frame(x1,x2,x3)
tr=t(x)

 names(tr) <- paste("G",ncol(tr),sep=".")
# tr
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# x1   55   60   75   80
# x2   30   20   15   23
# x3    4    3    2    6
# attr(,"names")
#  [1] "G.4" NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

How to rename  each new column in adataframe  by G1 for column(1), G2 for column(2),G3 for column(3) and G4 for column(4) like this

```
#      G1   G2   G3   G4
# x1   55   60   75   80
# x2   30   20   15   23
# x3    4    3    2    6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need the `colnames` argument

```
colnames(tr) <- paste0("G", 1:ncol(tr))
tr
#   G1 G2 G3 G4
#x1 55 60 75 80
#x2 30 20 15 23
#x3  4  3  2  6
```

because `tr` is a `matrix` and `matrix` is a `vector` with `dim` attribute.  So if we use `names`, it will just give the `name` attribute for each of the elements in the `matrix`

Comment: Are you just posting some wrong answer in order to make it a place holder until you will write a real answer?

Comment: akrun , is give me this error 
 `Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "G.4") : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Actually, I didn't see the `1:` in the OP's post, otherwise, it is a correct answer.  Also, the OP used `sep="."` and in the expected it is just `G1`, `G2` etc.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I was testing the code, but I copied the OP's code and didn't check the output.

Comment: I just trying to say that if you don't have an answer ready, posting something untested just to be first in order prevent others to post is unfair (in my opinion at least).

Comment: @DavidArenburg In this case, I know the `names` won't work and `colnames` work, but it was just that I didn't see the OP used `ncol` instead of `1:ncol`

Comment: @user5934339  I am using your code for creating the data and it worked for me.

Comment: @DavidArenburg  I think so, hopefully, the OP will test the updated one.